# Shorthand If / Else require_once PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, require-once

So Here's My Code. It Works When I Use Longer If Statement, But Not When I Use Shorthand. Sorry For My Bad English.

```
<?php 

function __autoload($class) {

    $path = "includes/{$class}.php";

    // IT WORKS LIKE THIS

     if (file_exists($path)) {

        require_once($path);

     }

     else {

        die("File Not Found :(");

     }

    //But Not Like This

    require_once() file_exists($path) ? $path : die("File Not Found :(");

}

?>
```

Comment: Your not working alternative isnt valid syntax, did just wont work require_once() file_exists($path). I strongly suggest you just use the composer autoloader, you wiol use it either way if you use any 3rd party code

Comment: it is a syntax error that's why it doesn't works.

Answer (score 0):

`file_exists($path) ? require_once($path) : die('file not found');`

But i think, shorthand if statement is proper to assign variables. i'd write this code like;

```
try {
    require_once($path); 
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die('file not found');
}
```